# How to extract the string after a word in C

Tags: c, string, string-matching

I am trying to add a functionality in my program that gets the specific word or sentence after a particular word in C.

E.g.
When I try to type:
"say Hello World", the program will print "Hello World" only.

My code runs like this:

```
int main(){
    char command;
    do{
        printf("MyOS>");
        scanf("%s", &command);
        if(strncmp(&command, "say", 3) == 0){
            //enter code here
        }
        } while (strncmp(&command, "exit", 4));
    return 0;
}
```

when running, the program asks for an input string, and in the case that my string starts with "say", I want it to output the next words/string.

Comment: You cannot store a string into a single `char` like `char command;`. That is U.B. A character array would be more appropriate.

Comment: The only printing is `printf("MyOS>");`.  Post true  code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems

1. `scanf("%s", &command);` here variable `command` requires a buffer of some size greater than 1.

Use as below
`#define COMMAND_SIZE 1024` and declare some thing like `char command[COMMAND_SIZE] = {0}`

2. I think you are trying to read multiword string, that is not possible with the way you used `scanf("%s", command);` even if command has sufficient size.

Better use `fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);` to read multiword strings.

In short you need some thing like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COMMAND_SIZE 512

int main(){
    
    char command[COMMAND_SIZE] = {0};
    do{
        printf("MyOS>");
        fgets(command,sizeof (command), stdin);
    
        if(strncmp(command, "say", 3) == 0) {
            printf(" %s\n", command+3);
        }
    } while (strncmp(command, "exit", 4));
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Make sure you allocate sufficient buffer to store your input command, and enter the input which is less than `COMMAND_SIZE` characters , so that it will have enough space the `\n`, else you will face problems with leftover `\n` characters.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much for your thorough explanation, I'm trying to study C independently and answers like this are very much appreciated.